# Inserting Pandas Dataframe into SQL Server Temporary Table: Table level constraint or index does not specify column list

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I have a rather large dataframe that needs to be stored in a temporary table so that values from this dataframe can be used in a subquery later.  I am struggling to insert the values from dataframe into the temporary table.

dataframe `testdf` holds email addresses in a single column.

[image]

Below is my code.  Certain values have been masked for security.  I am trying to create a temporary table `#temp2` and pass the values from `testdf` to it.  There is no index column in the testdf.  I was just trying to figure my way around the errors.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=xxxxxx.xxxxxx.com;"
                      "Database=xx;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

cursor=cnxn.cursor()

query = "CREATE TABLE #temp2 (Index INT, EMAIL VARCHAR(50))" # Creates temporary table

cursor.execute(query)

for row in testdf.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO #temp2 (Index, EMAIL) values(?,?)", row) #This is not working

cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Below is my error

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Just post the text.

Comment: Is it possible that the word `INDEX` has a special meaning in tsql? HINT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following modification worked:

```
for index, row in testdf.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO #temp2 (EMAIL) values(?)", row['EMAIL'])
```